# ”There are many who” vs ”Many are those who”

Tags: grammaticality, subject-verb-inversion

Is it grammatically correct to say:

> Many are those who enjoy camping

and is it any different in meaning than

> There are many (people) who enjoy camping

Comment: 'Many are those who enjoy camping' uses a literary style, better suited to a 1930s travel guide.

Comment: It is still grammatical, but it is archaic and overly dramatic.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are grammatical, but their connotations are slightly different. They focus on different things. "There are many who enjoy camping" says merely that the number of such people is large. In "Many are those who enjoy camping", "those who enjoy camping" is a noun phrase; the sentence speaks of them collectively, as a group. That is a focus which might or might not be desirable in another context.

You might, for example, write "Many are those who play chess at my local club.". This brings to mind a group of many people who come together there to play chess.

But does it work, to say "Many were those at the club last night"? That seems off to me. The context seems not to justify the unusual word order. Google has millions of hits for "many are those who" but very few for "many are those at".

Comment: +1 for noting the difference in emphasis. It is debatable, though, on precisely where the emphasis lies: the large number or the noun phrase.

Comment: I'd say the register of 'Many are they/those ...' is the greatest influence on connotation. And it's old-fashioned, literary, rather offbeat in everyday speech. [These Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there+are+many+who+enjoy%2Cmany+are+they+who+enjoy%2Cmany+are+those+who+enjoy&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20are%20many%20who%20enjoy%3B%2Cc0) seem to indicate that it's accordingly very rare.

Answer (score 0):

[NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=many+are+they+who%2Cmany+are+those+who&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmany%20are%20they%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmany%20are%20those%20who%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmany%20are%20they%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmany%20are%20those%20who%3B%2Cc0) shows "Many are they" being edged out by "Many are those." But as the first  appears in the King James Bible - "*Many are they who rise up against me*" - I guess it must be grammatically perfect! No, there's no difference in meaning between that and "There are many (people) who enjoy camping" or just "Many people enjoy camping."

Comment: The King James Bible definitely shouldn't be a style guide to modern English! Both are grammatical, but anything in the KJV should almost certainly be avoided.

Comment: @StuartF: The question asks, "Is it grammatically correct to say..."

Answer (score 0):

They are simply different ways of conveying basically the same idea.

Perhaps the simplest would be to say:

> Many enjoy camping.